# How do I zero-pad a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a number guesser that starts from 000001 and counts up all the way to 999999 how can I do that?

Comment: do you mean, "if i input a number, and an n, you want to print the output containing n digits?"

Comment: You can't do this with actual numbers like `int` or `float` but if you are able to use strings, then you can use string formatting to left-pad the numbers with a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) like this:

```
num = 2
print("num: {0:03d}".format(num))
```

output:

```
num: 002
```

Comment: What if I wanted to have the number of digits from a variable?

Comment: @JacksonLong I think the `num` is already a variable, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically choosing the pad-width:

```py
>>> num_digits = 6
>>> f"{str(x).rjust(num_digits, '0')}"
'000003'
>>> num_digits = 3
>>> f"{str(x).rjust(num_digits, '0')}"
'003'
>>> x = 521
>>> f"{str(x).rjust(num_digits, '0')}"
'521'
```

Comment: Seems you've edited your post, and now it's clear that dynamically choosing the pad-width is not what you need, so either use Hata's answer or slightly cleaner: `f"{x:>06}"`